# numbers as symbols for cnf transform in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cnf

how could I replace the letters in the number clause that served as symbols?
I used a sym library.

I have

```
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_cnf
from sympy.abc import A, B, D
to_cnf(~(A | B) | D)
cnf:
(D | ~A) & (D | ~B)
```

And I need replace letters with numbers

```
A as 1
B as 2
D as 2
```

example

```
 to_cnf(~(1 | 2) | 3)
    
    cnf:
    (3 | ~1) & (3 | ~2)
```

it is possible?